Build Error: Unmet Dependencies in `cuttlefish-frontend`
Build Error: Unmet Dependencies in cuttlefish-frontend
I went to download Cuttlefish and got this error
Error Description:
During the build process of cuttlefish-frontend, the following issues occurred:
After this operation, 9.216 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 382106 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cuttlefish-frontend-build-deps (1.0.0) ...
mk-build-deps: Unable to install cuttlefish-frontend-build-deps at /usr/bin/mk-build-deps line 402.
mk-build-deps: Unable to install all build-dep packages
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package cuttlefish-frontend
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 1.0.0
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution UNRELEASED
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by Jorge Moreira <jemoreira@google.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build frontend
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: debhelper-compat (= 12) golang (>= 2:1.13~) | golang-1.13 libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)

Issues Encountered:

Dependency Issues:

debhelper-compat (= 12) is required but missing.
golang (>= 2:1.13~) or golang-1.13 is needed.
libprotobuf-dev and protobuf-compiler are also missing.


Build Aborted:
The build process is aborted due to unmet dependencies.


System Information:

Source package: cuttlefish-frontend
Source version: 1.0.0
Architecture: amd64
Build Environment: Ubuntu 18.04


I can't find any official documentation for installing debhelper-compat (= 12) on ubuntu 18.04 at the moment.
Does anyone have a solution for resolving these unmet dependencies or alternative suggestions to bypass this issue?

I could solve a very similiar issue using the following way:
I followed the official instruction to install bazel, using bazelisk, but this is not the correct approach, when the goal is to use dpkg-buildpackage afterwards.
There is another link in the bazel documentation that explains how to add bazel to the apt repositiries and install it from there:
https://bazel.build/install/ubuntu#install-on-ubuntu
After doing this, your bazel installation should be fine and the cuttlefish will swim.
BR
JP
